# Why am I getting the warning Unchecked assignment?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class defined like this:

```
public class SymEncryptedData<VerifierType extends JSONable> implements JSONable {
   // ...

   public SymEncryptedData encrypt(Key key, byte[] payload, VerifierType verifier) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

where `JSONable` is an interface. Then, I create an instance of it like this:

```
SymEncryptedData<Verifier> symEncryptedData = new SymEncryptedData<Verifier>().encrypt(randomKey, PAYLOAD.getBytes(), VERIFIER);
```

which works, but I'm getting a warning about Unchecked assignment. Why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: What is the **exact** warning/error you receive?

Comment: Maybe because your `encrypt` method returns a `SymEncryptedData`, that you are assigning to a `SymEncryptedData<Verifier>` variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
public SymEncryptedData encrypt(Key key, byte[] payload, VerifierType verifier) {
```

to

```
public SymEncryptedData<VerifierType> encrypt(Key key, byte[] payload, VerifierType verifier) {
```

You get an unchecked assignment warning when you assign a raw value to a parametrized variable.

Answer (score 2):

`encrypt` returns a raw type `SymEncryptedData`. Add the type parameter and the warning should go away:

```
 public SymEncryptedData<VerifierType> encrypt(Key key, byte[] payload, VerifierType verifier)
```

Comment: I don't think `SymEncryptedData` would be the type